# How to Give Link In Menu to go menu page (laravel 4.2)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

Hello Friend Thank For viewing My Question!!

I am Unable to make my menu link active

### my view file code

```
<div class="sign-up-right">
    <a href="{{ URL::route('singup') }}">Sign Up</a>
</div>
```

My Controller File(MyCon.php)

```
public function singup(){
    return View::make('preview',['preview'=>'signup.php']);
}
```

My Routes file code

```
Route::get('/', 'MyCon@index');
route::get('admin', array('user'=>'Admin@index'));

Route::get('/login',function(){ return View::make('preview',['preview'=>'login.php']);});

Route::get('singup', ['as' => 'signup', 'uses' => 'MyCon@signup']);
```

But when I am click on Signup link It Show Error Like

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException



    return new Response('', 200, array('Allow' => implode(',', $others)));
        }))->bind($request);
    }
    $this->methodNotAllowed($others);
}

protected function methodNotAllowed(array $others)
{
    throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException($others);
}

protected function check(array $routes, $request, $includingMethod = true)
```

please help to make my link successful
Thank

Comment: Unrelated, but you're misspelling "signup" everywhere. EDIT** actually it may be related, because you spell it correctly, and incorrectly every other attempt.

Comment: The funcions you posted are incomplete, so it's hard to really determine the problem, but inconsistent spelling and poor formatting are going to lead to lots of problems. It's worth the effort to make code pretty. You'll see why.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the name to your route may solve your problem

```
Route::post('singup', function(){ return View::make('preview',['preview'=>'signup.php']);});
```

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\Route::name()

Comment: Route::post('singup', function(){ return View::make('preview',['preview'=>'signup.php']);}); try this

Comment: again this Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException on signup page

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a simple `a href` link, you need to change the route to `Route::get`:

```
Route::get('singup', ['as' => 'signup', 'uses' => 'MyCon@signup']);
```

Also, fix the link:

```
<a href="{{{ URL::route('signup') }}}">Sign Up</a>
```

Comment: Method [signup] does not exist.

This error Show Please Help Bro

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\Route::name()

Comment: @akashjha oh, you're using 4.2. Fixed. Also, update the link as I've shown.

Comment: and error like Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException

Comment: @akashjha make sure the view ends with `.blade.php`. Also, please show the whole routes file.

Comment: please check complete route file

Comment: @akashjha the routes look fine. But make sure the link is `laravel.sdcsd.in/signup`. Looks like you're using `.php` instead of `.blade.php`